# Mac PHP can't write to .log file

Tags: php, html, macos

I tried to host a simple website on my Mac. My goal is to make a form that everyone can enter text in, then the piece of text will be shown in the main HTML page. I encountered two problems:

- I could see updates in `mylog.log` when I run `php submit.php`, but I can't when using a browser (Safari) and visiting the site itself.
- Even if I managed to write to the file, I don't know how to make the HTML interact with it to display the contents.

This is the code in `index.html`:

```html
<form action="submit.php" method="post" target="_self">
  <input type="text" id="textform2" name="msg">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And `submit.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Processing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
<?php
$message = 'hi';
$file = 'mylog.log';
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $message);
fclose($handle);
?>
    <p class="par">Our server is processing your request. You will be redirected…</p>
    <script> location.replace("http://johann.local"); </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- I put these files in `Macintosh/Library/WebServer/Documents`.
- Sanitisation is not required since it will only be hosted on my private WiFi network.

Comment: which web server do you use? You can try run `php -S localhost:5000` in Documents directory, and then try to go `localhost:5000`

Comment: That worked well! Thank you so much. (I still need help with my second question)

Comment: No problem :) . And, I don't understand your second question. Can you explain it more? Thanks

Comment: Let's assume I have the text "I love PHP" in `mylog.log`. How do I set an HTML element's content to "I love PHP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to run PHP Web Server to make your `submit.php` working.
Go to your directory with index.html and submit.php, and run this:

```sh
php -S localhost:5000
```

Then your website is available at http://localhost:5000 .

About your second question, if you want easily write into the file, you can use `file_put_contents` function instead of `fopen/fwrite/fclose`, and vice versa, you can easily read the content via `file_get_contents`.

This is example of usage:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Processing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
<?php
$message = 'hi';
$file = 'mylog.log';
file_put_contents($file, $message); // save $message into $file
?>
    <p class="par">Our server is processing your request. You will be redirected…</p>
    <p>Contents of the log: <?php echo file_get_contents($file); ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

(I removed the redirection to see the content)
With echo function combined with file_get_contents, you can print the contents of the log file into the HTML.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't solve my problem. I still can't see anything in the log file.

Comment: Would it be possible, too, to do the `echo file_get_contents($file);` part with Javascript? I would like to put the results in the main `index.html` page.

Comment: Javascript will not help you. If you want to put it into index.html, you need to rename it to index.php and then just use file_get_contents as susual